# how to fetch datetime along with GMT appended with it in mysql?

Tags: mysql, datetime, utc

I was looking for "how to fetch datetime along with UTC appended with it" in mysql. but i dont find any proper solution in stackoverflow.

Many suggested to convert datetime to required utc within query itself by assigning default_time_zone but i want to convert the datetime at user end depends on their system settings.

I have a field called "**created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**"

whenever i fetch data, i am getting date as "**yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**" (ex. *2015-04-01 11:30:25*)

but the format i want is "**2015-04-01 11:30:25 +5:30**" where (**+5:30** is default_time_zone of the server) so that i can convert it at user end as "**2015-04-01 10:30:25**" (assuming user's timezone is **+4:30**)

so my question is **how to fetch datetime along with UTC appended with it in mysql so that i can convert it at user end depend on their system settings?**

Comment: How your dates are saved in DB ? When you save date in DB what timezone it saves ? Provide some sample data and expected result out of it.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty done bro. check it..

Comment: You save it in a `timestamp` type of field.

Comment: UTC, to put it bluntly, means "no time zone", which is awesome because you can apply time zones and shift the time offset. What you want to do is save the time you get from the user using their time zone, then you want to offset that for another user with another time zone. That's wrong and that's way too much work. You save all the dates in UTC (that's the `timestamp` column) and you deliver all the dates as UTC - after that, you said you use users' time zone - which is perfect, since your job is super easy then. Basically just save everything as UTC, job done.

Comment: Alternatively, you can take the hard route and try to apply a complex solution to a trivial problem. It's much easier to use the language of your choice and convert someone's time to UTC and send that to the DB instead of saving their time plus their time offset. Apparently you are using something to insert data into MySQL - just add one or two lines of code to make dates UTC, send that, forget about all problems you might ever have with dates and time zones. But, as I said, if you don't want this easy approach - I wish you find the solution that satisfies you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved ! Rather than appending timezone, i have set my server's default timezone as +00:00 so whenever i insert a data then the date will be  like (eg. **2015-05-11 05:30:10**) which is based on server's default timezone.

At user end, i fetch the data and will change the datetime format based on there system settings. for ex: if the user's system time zone is **+4:00** then the date will be convert from

> 2015-05-11 **05:30**:10 to 2015-05-11 **09:30**:10.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_format()` function or `concat` function to append anything you want while selecting

```
select date_format('2015-04-01 11:30:25','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s +5:30') as date ;
+---------------------------+
| date                      |
+---------------------------+
| 2015-04-01 11:30:25 +5:30 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select concat('2015-04-01 11:30:25',' +5:30') as date ;
+---------------------------+
| date                      |
+---------------------------+
| 2015-04-01 11:30:25 +5:30 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```